# How to get email address in outlook email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I able to send an email with HTML embedded to the recipient. The email is mainly to allow the recipient to approve/reject an request. When the recipient clicks on the approve/reject button, it will trigger a web service to run a job. 
Now, I would like to make sure the web service is trigger by a correct email account. Therefore, I wish I could get the email address of the current account when the user clicks on the buttons.

HTML code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>HTML Email</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td><img width="150" src="http://onlineimage/images/global/us/logo.gif " /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr style="width:98%" />
    <br />Hi,
    <br />
    <br />You have a request. Please kindly approve or reject by click on the buttons below
    <br />Thank You.
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="https://webservice/process_request?P1_APPROVAL_TOKEN=85FF353E166C2281E05400144FF8364B&P1_APPROVAL_REQUEST_ID=67&P1_ACTION=APPROVE" style="border-radius: 2px; background-color: #5794ff; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 19px; height: 32px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 12px; text-decoration: none">APPROVE</a>
    <a href="https://webservice/process_request?P1_APPROVAL_TOKEN=85FF353E166C2281E05400144FF8364B&P1_APPROVAL_REQUEST_ID=67&P1_ACTION=REJECT" style="border-radius: 2px; background-color: #5794ff; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 19px; height: 32px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 12px; text-decoration: none">REJECT</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the one generating the email, why not insert the recipient's address into the link url for your webservice?

Comment: The approval email will be sent to the approver/recipient.  We're trying to avoid if the recipient accidentally forward the email to someone who should not have access to approve the request. Therefore, before we start to process the approval, probably we need to verify the email address of triggering this approval.

Comment: You can't without having something running on the client side - Outlook won't run any scripts in an HTML message, so a static link is the best you can do.